# [unixODBC][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved. Reason code: "3"

Tags: php, db2, unixodbc

I get the following error when i run apache 2.4 with php 8.1.2, but it works from command line.
The driver is ibm V11.5.7 with license community edition.
I set the DB2 instance and chmod 777 the sqllib.

I think its runs by www-data or root. When i exec isql, is by xx user, the root user dont have the path append.
PD: if i exec "sudo isql xx xx xx" get a similar error '[IM004][unixODBC][DriverManager] Driver 's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed.
[ISQL] ERROR:Could not SQLConnect

```
My odbcinst file
[ODBC Data Sources]
[IBM i Access ODBC Driver]
Driver=/home/xx/sqllib/lib32/libdb2.so
Driver64=/home/xx/sqllib/lib64/libdb2.so
```

IBM_DB_HOME=/home/xx/sqllib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/xx/sqllib/lib64:/home/xx/sqllib/lib64/gskit:/home/xx/sqllib/lib32
PATH of xx have /home/xx/sqllib/bin

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to correctly export two environment variables __IBM_DB_HOME__ and __LD_LIBRARY_PATH__ in addition to ensuring __PATH__ variable has the clidriver/bin directory appended?

Comment: Which PHP version? Do you run PHP from a different userid/account than you test php ibm_db at the command-line?  Are these variables set for each account/userid? IS the .../sqllib/bin also on the PATH (for the userid that runs php). Best to give full and precise details in your question text (please edit your question to add new facts, please don't use comments because they are not searchable ).

Comment: You should run apache as a nonroot user. Apart from that, you need to configure the apache so that the account it uses has its environment variables configured correctly for php and the php_ibm_db module.  This is not a programming question but is instead just a configuration question. Refer to the apache documentation for the detail, or see many similar questions on configuring apache correctly.